# Initializing multiple array values, and utilizing them in a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Drawing extends JPanel
{
    private Color borderColor = Color.BLACK;
    private int[] borderX1 = {0};
    private int[] borderY1 = {0};
    private int[] borderX2 = {500};
    private int[] borderY2 = {300};
/**
 * Constructor for objects of Drawing class type
 */
 public Drawing( Color background )
{
    setBackground( background );
}

public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    // calls the paintComponent method defined within the parent class, JPanel
    super.paintComponent( g );

    // display words (i.e. string, text)
    g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
    // Sets starting coordinate for first letter.
    g.drawString( "My Name", 375, 50 );

    // draw various shapes with different colors
    // Shapes - (x1,y1,x2,y2);
    g.setColor( Color.RED );
    g.fillRect( 100, 100, 70, 50 );  
    g.drawRect( 100, 170, 70, 50 ); 

    g.setColor( Color.GREEN );
    g.fillOval( 120, 10, 70, 50 );  
    g.drawOval( 20, 50, 70, 50 ); 

    g.setColor( Color.MAGENTA );
    g.drawRect( 25, 50, 150, 150 ); 

    g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
    g.drawLine( 200, 140, 300, 100 );  
    g.drawLine( 300, 100, 400, 140 );  
    g.drawRect( 200, 140, 200, 100 );  

    // Border
    g.setColor ( borderColor );
    g.drawRect( 0, 0, 500, 300);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i ++) {
        borderX1[i] =  ( borderX1[i-1] + 1 );
        borderX1[i] =  ( borderY1[i-1] + 1 );
        borderX1[i] =  ( borderX2[i-1] - 1 );
        borderX1[i] =  ( borderY2[i-1] - 1 );
        g.drawRect( borderX1[i], borderY1[i], borderX2[i], borderY2[i] );
}

}
}
```

The focus of this topic is the for loop near the end of the code, and the multiple int[] arrays that I initialized at the beginning.

I wanted to create a border for my application, yet I wanted to be able to adjust the thickness. I created an array, and I attempted to adjust the values of then next position of the array by adding or subtracting one from the previous position.

In a nutshell, I am attempting to create multiple borders by repeating the same line of code within a for loop. This way that it the border gives the appearance of a single, thick border.

My question being, is this a valid use for a for loop? Does each iteration of the for loop remove the previous border of the for loop from existence? If the former is true, is there anyway to utilize a for loop in such a way?

Oh, and I am new to Java (and programming), so my syntax is probably off, but I am simply curious about the logic used in the for loop.

EDIT:

@Johnny --> Thanks for the input. I will attempt to reconfigure the arrays.

@Micheal Pickett --> I am using what I am using because it is required for my class. I have a little bit of programming experience, but I am not to familiar with arrays, so I figured I would take this moment to learn about them.

And yes, it was a copying mistake, good catch.

Comment: I think you need to understand [arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays) first. All your arrays have size 1 you need to initialize them like: `int[] array = new int[500];` Since your arrays only are of size 1 you will run into `OutOfBoundExceptions` in the for loop.

Comment: You should probably look in to using Javafx instead of swing. It can easily do this using css As for your question, it looks like you are overwriting all of your calls to borderX1[i] = except for the last one. borderX1[i] =  ( borderY2[i-1] - 1 ); I'm not sure if this was a copying mistake of meant to be this way. So the only code in that for loop that matters are the last two lines.